# How to create a checked listView with images

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox

I want to create a listView that has in every row a checkBox, an image, and Text. I also want the rows presented like a listBox's, not like a grid(every item is below the predecessor item). So I tried this:

```
Imagelist.ImageSize = new Size(32, 32);
int count = 0;
listView1.LargeImageList = Imagelist;
listView1.CheckBoxes = true;
listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
List<string> names = new List<string>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
foreach (string s in names)
{
    ListViewItem lst = new ListViewItem();
    lst.Text = s;
    lst.Tag = count;
    lst.ImageIndex = count++;
    lst.SubItems.Add(s);
    listView1.Items.Add(lst);
}
```

But I have this presentation:

[image]

And when I add this line:

```
listView1.View = View.Tile;
```

I got this exception:

```
les cases à cocher (checkboxes) ne sont pas prises en charge en mode tile. choisissez un autre mode d'affichage ou définissez checkboxes à false.
```

this what i want:

[image]

Comment: from your loop remove the subitem adding and also set your listview imagelist as smallimagelist and should do the trick.

Comment: i do as you said but it's not working :(, no image visible and also i got the same presentation

Comment: i forgot...the View property must be smallicon with the smallimagelist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for you @terrybozzio, but i used an open source controle [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/index.html). and it's great.